# Playing mp3-file on linux with Qt5-Multimedia fails

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gstreamer

I am using a `QMediaPlayer` Object to play a mp3-file.

```
void play_mp3(std::string path)
{
    QMediaPlayer *player = QMediaPlayer();
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(path.c_str()));
    player->setVolume(100);
    player->play();
}
```

The following problem occurs:

> GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file://[path]"

What is wrong?

Comment: other files are working? say wav,ogg or something?

Comment: wav throws the same error...

Comment: ogg says: QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread

Comment: this is weird.. what version of Qt and gstreamer do you use? and what platform(OS)? also try to add as many related infos as possible.. we are not magicians (I know you are new at SO) :)

Comment: i am using a linux machine (ubuntu). I am using Qt 4.8.6 and gstreamer 1.0 <br /> I installed additionally qtmultimedia5... if you need any more information you could write me (actually i don't know which information could be important for you) and thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: ok lets try it the other way.. open up terminal an execute: `gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///home/user/some.mp3 ! queue ! autoaudiosink` - is it playing correctly? check if you have installed all the libgstreamer-plugins-* (base, good, bad, ugly.. especially ugly because of the mp3` ..

Comment: okay: the command you suggested works correctly. My installed plugins are: base, good and bad. Ugly is currently not installed

Comment: i just installed ugly but the code is still not working :/

Comment: ok so go to QtCreator > Project > Run settings > unfold Env Variables section (or Build? PATH should be there or something..) and add GST_DEBUG with value 3 and then rerun, or if you do not have QtCreator you can run as `GST_DEBUG=3 ./yourapp`

Comment: i fixed the problem by working with gstreamer directly (no more QT) - but thank you for your efforts! :)